# Unrecognized file format in stored as clause CSV Hive

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create a csv hive table (using Hive CLI) into S3.

```
create external table hello (
name INT)
stored as csv
location 's3://bucket/myfolder;
```

==> Error SemanticException `Unrecognized file format in stored as clause 'CSV'`

I deleted EXTERNAL

```
create table hello (
name INT)
stored as csv
location 's3://bucket/myfolder;
```

==> The same Error SemanticException `Unrecognized file format in stored as clause 'CSV'`

Knowing that I'm using an Apache Hive + Apache Hadoop (I installed it because Hive need some hadoop binaries).

Do you have an idea please, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is not a valid file type. Try this instead:

```
create external table hello (
name INT)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://bucket/myfolder';
```

Or

```
create external table hello (
name INT)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
stored as textfile
location 's3://bucket/myfolder';
```